# TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str when trying to return something from api

Tags: python, json, python-requests

I am coding a discord bot that uses the mojang and hypixel API. I am trying to return the first line (gameType and mode only)

```
{"success":true,"games":[{"date":1588679703604,"gameType":"DUELS","mode":"CLASSIC_DUEL","map":"Neon"},{"date":1588679671468,"gameType":"DUELS","mode":"CLASSIC_DUEL","map":"Skyport"},{"date":1588679612412,"gameType":"DUELS","mode":"CLASSIC_DUEL","map":"Arena"},{"date":1588679573171,"gameType":"DUELS","mode":"CLASSIC_DUEL","map":"Spikerock Bay"},{"date":1588679530855,"gameType":"DUELS","mode":"CLASSIC_DUEL","map":"Backwood"},{"date":1588679503914,"gameType":"DUELS","mode":"CLASSIC_DUEL","map":"Spikerock Bay"},{"date":1588679453072,"gameType":"DUELS","mode":"CLASSIC_DUEL","map":"Highset"},
```

This is how I have been doing it:

```
def get_session(name):
    url1 = f"https://api.mojang.com/users/profiles/minecraft/{name}"

    res = requests.get(url1)
    data = res.json()
    if data["id"] is None:
        return None
    returnUuid = (data["id"])

    url2 = f"https://api.hypixel.net/recentGames?key={API_KEY}&uuid=" + returnUuid

    res = requests.get(url2)
    data = res.json()
    if data["games"] is None:
        return None
    returnGametype = (data["games"]["gameType"])
    returnGamemode = (data["games"]["mode"])
```

It is giving me an error though, `Command Raised an exception: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str.`

I am assuming it has something to do with having multiple lines. I'm not sure what to do though.

Comment: Can you add a line number of the error and print data variable?

Comment: Their answer has pointed out your problem.if you want to get all the `["gameType"]` or `["mode"]`.you need to use a for loop to do that.

Answer (score 0):

The dictionaries are nested in a list. That is the reason for the index error (as list indexes cannot be a string). If you want to use the first result in the "games" list use the first index (0):

```py
game_type = data["games"][0]["gameType"]
game_mode = data["games"][0]["mode"]
```

Answer (score 0):

As you noticed, it has something to do with multiple lines.

```
{"success":true,"games":[
{"date":1588679703604,"gameType":"DUELS","mode":"CLASSIC_DUEL","map":"Neon"},
{"date":1588679671468,"gameType":"DUELS","mode":"CLASSIC_DUEL","map":"Skyport"}...]
```

The endpoint returns json, that for key `'games'` has an array/multiple values. 
So if you want to get the `'gameType'` and `'mode'` value for first element in the array, you have to write:

```
 returnGametype = (data["games"][0]["gameType"])
 returnGamemode = (data["games"][0]["mode"])
```